# Unable to save data using parse.com service

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have just started using Parse.com for back-end purpose for Android application. Although this seems to be trivial but I am struggling to get through. I followed basics step to test if data was sent. But I am not able to get it. My application on emulator ran successfully. At log level, I am seeing error with a log message : **Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}**

I shall be grateful if any body can guide me through this scenario. I have also copied down the snippet of code.

ParseApplication.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this,  MY_APPLICATION_ID, MY_CLIENT_KEY");
    /*// Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, YOUR_APPLICATION_ID, YOUR_CLIENT_KEY);*/
}
```

ParseStarterProjectActivity.java

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
}
```

AndriodManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  package="com.parse.starter"  android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name="ParseApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ParseStarterProjectActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you were making changes in APPLICATION ID and CLIENT KEY,that are not acceptible, try the same keys given at parse website page which come with your project name, hope you will get rid of this problem....

Comment: For my case it was the problem .

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but in your manifest, application name should have the full path:

```
android:name="com.parse.starter.ParseApplication"
```

ParseApplication is never instantiated, so your Parse.initialize is never called.